# Making a CSS menu with hover animation

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, menu, hover

I am making a menu with 2 items per line and I want them to have a background-image and on hover the image will change to other. I was able to do it in chrome, using content in CSS, but Firefox and IE don't support this. Thus it should be made with background-image. The problem of this is that with content I can specify that the buttons will have 35% of the width and height of the left side while making this with background-image is impossible, I need to say specifically that they will have px of height and that will not make it resize when I resize the window. When I resize the window the left side resizes thus what's inside of it resizes automatically because I defined 35% of it. Here is an example code of how I made it (works in chrome, not in firefox and IE). Can someone help me doing this with background-image and still resize the buttons when I resize the window?

https://jsfiddle.net/37qbtwak/

```
ul.sidebar-menu li a span {
width:35%;
height:35%;
border:1px solid;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a span#menu_sensor {
content: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%; /*  Safari  */
-khtml-background-size: 100% 100%; /*  Konqueror  */
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%; /*  Firefox  */
}
```

With background-image I have to do it like this:

```
ul.sidebar-menu li a span#menu_sensor {
content: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
height:100px;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%; /*  Safari  */
-khtml-background-size: 100% 100%; /*  Konqueror  */
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%; /*  Firefox  */
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: Why don't you just put the actual image in there?

Comment: Why not just set background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a valid use of the `content` property, which is only intended to be used on pseudo elements.

If you set the `display` property of your spans to `inline-block`, you can set a height relative to the width using the `padding` property. Then set the `background-size` property to `contain` and center your image(s).

```css
ul.sidebar-menu{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li{
    margin:0 0 50px;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li.sub-menu{
    line-height:15px;
}
ul.sidebar-menu li.sub-menu a{
    color:#aeb2b7;
    margin-bottom:0 20px 30px 10px;
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:all .3s ease;
}
ul.sidebar-menu a span {
    border:1px solid;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 0 12.25%;
    width:35%;
}
#menu_sensor{
    background:url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png') center center no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
}
#menu_sensor:hover,#menu_sensor:focus{
    background-image:url('http://www.webyposicionamientoseo.com/base/ui/images/blog/27-google-hummingbird.jpg');
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
    <li class="sub-menu">
        <a href="/sensor"><span id="menu_sensor"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```